# Set the value of an input field with Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, jinja2, webapp2

I have an app written with Python webapp2. I render a template with a few variables like so:

```
template_values = {
            'name': "Test"
        }
template_values = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/leaderboard.html')
self.response.write(leaderboard_template.render(template_values))
```

I want to set the text of an input field  in HTML using `{{name}}`, but this didn't work. Any ideas?

`<input type="text" value="{{name}}">`

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I'm also using AngularJS. It's also fine if I can set the `ng-model` property of the input field to a template value.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What is the output currently?

Comment: The field text is empty, but the html is properly updated with <input type="text" value="Test">

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with [wtforms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) if you like.

Comment: How about with AngularJS?

Comment: If you can connect it to your backend but I didn't try it. I do it with wtforms + jinja2 + webapp2 that is a good combination. You should also be able to achieve it without wtforms if you can't add a library. WTForms will also include validation if you plan a more advanced form.